# How to test insulation of an unarmored, buried cable with mega-ohmmeter?

Tags: power, cables

I have 3 single 1000V rated cables that have no armor and there is no ground reference (they are in a trench in the middle of the field). Usually I do phase to phase and phase to ground for each conductor. But because I don't have ground point, I only did phase-to-phase. Does phase to phase value tell me something if the insulation is defective ?

Comment: What if _one_ of the conductors have a piece of bad insulation that causes it to leak to ground? At least bring a grounding rod with you into that field and measure between that and each of the phases. (Which you ought to do even if the cable has a conductor labeled "ground").

Comment: I wonder if this belongs in the DIY stack exchange?

Comment: Try reading this: http://www.cablejoints.co.uk/upload/Megger_Cable_Fault_Finding_Solutions.pdf

Comment: @mkeith -  I would say no.  This is not home wiring.

Comment: If only one cable has an isolation fault, phase to phase isolation measurement doesn't tell you exactly which cable is defective. If the soil of the trench is somewhat conductive, a test with several grounding rods may help to locate the fault. But you will need a special instrument for measuring ground resistance from rod to rod and from rod to cables.

Answer (score 2):

A fail on an insulation test tells you a cable is bad but a pass doesn't tell you it's good.

Banging in a ground rod and testing too it may help find some faults but if the cable is not yet burried or if the soil it's packed in is too dry or loose it may well leave issues undisocvered.

I can't give specific advive on regulations as I don't know what country you are in but the whole situation seems dodgy as heck to me.